# Is there an free open source alternative to smart sockets?

Tags: publish-subscribe

I googled it but couldn't really find one. Anybody aware of one?

Comment: http://www.middleware.org/mom/basicmom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/). I know nothing about SmartSockets, but the Wikipedia blurb suggests that they are similar in nature.

Comment: This one looks good. Despite of the blinding red in their web site. :D

Comment: P.S - Smartsockets is just a message based publish/subscribe middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with SmartSockets, but it seems to be a messaging system. A popular messaging system under the Mozilla Public License is [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). Is this the type of thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

SmartSockets is/was a hub-and-spoke messaging system. One of the key selling points of SmartSockets was that it *just worked*, was well-documented, performant and easy to program with.

Of the alternatives that exist today in the OSS world, I'd have to point to [NATS](https://www.nats.io) from Apcera as the open source hub-and-spoke solution that is closest to SmartSockets in terms of simplicity, ease of use and performance. No complex APIs to learn, no arcane configuration magic, no external dependencies. Definitely recommend that anyone who was happy with SmartSockets give NATS a try!

(***Shill disclaimer***: I am a former employee of Talarian Corporation, the maker of SmartSockets, as well as its successor, TIBCO Software, and am now employed by Apcera, maker of NATS. This means I'm well-versed in both solutions, and am definitely interested in seeing everybody try NATS!)

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for open source alternatives for a publish-subscribe system, you should look at Data Distribution Service implementations.

DDS is an [OMG standard](http://portals.omg.org/dds/) for real-time publish-subscribe middleware. Currently there are two open source implementations:

1. [Open DDS](http://www.opendds.org)
2. [OpenSplice DDS Community Edition](http://www.opensplice.org)